# ¿Es posible enviar una variable desde el controlador a un archivo config, en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

estoy trabajando con Codeigniter 3, tengo un archivo config (form_validation.php) en el cual tengo todas mis reglas de validación.

Dentro de mi archivo de configuración (form_validation.php) tengo un método que necesita recibir una variable (en este caso el user_id) aquí el código -

```
$config = array(
        'edit_user' => array(
          array(
                     'field' => 'edituser_email',
                     'label' => 'Email',
                     'rules' => "required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|edit_unique[users.email.$user_id]",
                     'errors' => array(
                        'required' => 'Campo obligatorio.',
                        'valid_email' => 'Formato de correo no válido.',
                        'edit_unique' => 'Ya existe un usuario con este correo.'
                     )
          )
        )
);
```

Pero no logro enviar la variable ($user_id) desde mi controlador -

```
$data['user_id'] = $id;
if ($this->form_validation->run('edit_user',$data) === FALSE)
```

Obtengo error : ***Message: Undefined variable: user_id***

Alguno de ustedes ha intentado hacer esto, se que desde el método en mi Controlador, puedo añadir todas mis reglas; pero deseo mantener de forma separada estas reglas, mediante una archivo config.

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Estás enviando un array. Debes recibirlo como tal. Es por eso que te indica la variable que no reconoce `user_id`. Si te fijas, cuando aparece este tipo de errores es por que la función no ha hecho referencia a la variable user_id, quizá con un `var_dump` puedas leer ó puedes probar enviando

`if ($this->form_validation->run('edit_user',$data['user_id']) === FALSE)`
y ver que te arroja.

Comment: Hola Leroy, esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta. ¿Podrías añadir algo más de información sobre cómo hacer `$data['user_id']` en lugar de sólo `$data` solucionaría el problema? Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu corrección @AlvaroMontoro, me aparece deshabilitada la opción de comentar. Es por ello que coloco la respuesta. Sin embargo puedo editar para la corrección que me sugieres.